# how to display simple information using <core-list-dart>

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, core-elements

I saw several posts here but I still can't succeed display anything...

I try to run the example in the source code.
https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/lib/core_list_dart.html

this is my dart code

```dart
@CustomTag('exercise-list')
class ExerciseList extends PolymerElement {

  @observable int testBind = 50000;
  @observable ObservableList data;

  @observable int index;
  @observable bool selected;

  ExerciseList.created() : super.created();

  @override
  void onReady() {

    data = toObservable([
        new Person('Bob', true),
        new Person('Tim', false)
    ]);
  }
}

class Person extends Observable {
    @observable String name;
    @observable bool checked;

    Person(this.name, this.checked);
}
```

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../packages/core_elements/core_list_dart.html">
<polymer-element name="exercise-list">

    <template>

        test : {{testBind}}

        <core-icon icon="star"></core-icon>


        <core-list-dart data="{{data}}">
            <template>
                <div class="row {{ {selected: selected} }}" style="height: 80px">
                    List row: {{index}}, User data from model: {{model.name}}
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{model.checked}}">
                </div>
            </template>
        </core-list-dart>

    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="exercise_list.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

```yml
name: app 
version: 0.0.1 
description: app 
environment: 
  sdk: '>=1.2.0 <2.0.0' 
dependencies: 
  browser: any 
  guinness: any 
  paper_elements: '>=0.6.0+2 <0.7.0' 
  core_elements: '>=0.5.0+2 <0.6.0' 
  polymer: '>=0.15.3 <0.16.0' 
  unittest: any 
transformers: 
- polymer: 
    entry_points: web/index.html
```

The value testBing and the core-icon are well displayed. It's weird I can't understand where is my problem... Hope you will find the problem. Cheers !

#### Update

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/polymer-dart-examples) is an example of the bare minimum  code to display something with core-list-dart. note the mandatory fields in the model !!!

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

There are a few issues with your code:

**exercise_list.dart**

- You are overriding `onReady` which is a getter not a method and can't
  be overridden. You want to override `ready` instead.
- When I load the page I get exceptions telling me that Person doesn't 
  have a `selected` or `index` property. I added them to the class to
  get rid of the error without investigating why this is necessary.

```js
class Person extends Observable {
    @observable String name;
    @observable bool checked;
    bool selected = false; // <== added
    int index; // <== added

    Person(this.name, this.checked);
}
```

**exercise_list.html**

- I removed `model.` from `{{model.name}}` and `{{model.checked}}`

Now the list is displayed.

All these things were reported by the development environment. I use WebStorm but I'm sure the same hints and errors would be shown by DartEditor and also by Dartium when run directly (shown in the developer tools console).

You can't reference fields of your `exercise_list` element in the `template` element passed to `core-list-dart` because the `template` is removed and applied inside the `core-list-dart` which changes its scope.
This is why `selected` and `index` didn't work here.

#### Old

I guess the problem is that the `core-list-dart` needs an explicit height to be displayed but your code doesn't show how it is added to your page. (see also this discussion https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/47#issuecomment-63126241)

The height is probably only applied if you set your element to `display: block`

```dart
<polymer-element name="exercise-list">

    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
        core-list-dart {
          height: 500px;
        }
      </style>

      ....
```

Comment: Great !! thx !! one thing weird though, I had no error messages in dartium :(

Comment: I'm not so sure anymore about the `onReady` being reported at runtime. Don't you use DartEditor? You can use `analyzer` from command line too which definitely should report this error.

Comment: I'm using webstorm as well... I'm up to date so I don't know why it does not work. maybe some config stuff because I'm using it not fir a long time

Comment: Interesting. For me it showed a squiggled underline just after opening the file from the cloned Git repo. I'm also not yet very fluent yet with the setup options.

Comment: my last commit on the repo doesn't work with the very last version of polymer,core_element_paper_element...

Comment: Same here, I'm investigating.

Comment: Seems now you need the `model.` prefix when referencing model fields (`{{model.name}}` instead of `{{name}}`).

Comment: I started to have advice by adding the style part -->         <style> ...  </style> same as you provide